# QComboBox ListView is occuping combobox frame

Tags: c++, qt, listview, stylesheet, qcombobox

the comboBox contains two entries and , when the combobox is clicked, the listview occupies the frame of combobox. I want the list view just below the combobox. stylesheet is as shown below:

```
QComboBox {
border: 1px solid #8F9EAB;
border-radius: 3px;
font: 16pt "Arial";
min-width: 6em;
color: #1B3067;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
padding-left:10px;
} 
QComboBox:pressed
{
border: 1px solid #1562AD; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: #87A6D5;
} 
QComboBox:disabled
{
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF; 
color: #BFBFBF;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
} 
QComboBox::down-arrow
{ 
background-image: url(:/Images/data/img/Images/DOWN_enabled.png);
height: 7px;
width : 13px;
}
QComboBox::drop-down 
{ 
subcontrol-position: top right;
width: 40px;
color: white;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-left-color: #8F9EAB;
border-left-style: solid; 
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; 
}
QComboBox QListView
{
font: 16pt "Arial";
color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item 
{
border-bottom: 5px solid white; margin:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the `view()` can not be handled with Qt Style Sheet, you must create a class that inherits from `QComboBox` and overwrite the `showPopup()` method as shown below.

```
class ComboBox: public QComboBox{
public:
    using QComboBox::QComboBox;
public:
    void showPopup(){
        QComboBox::showPopup();
        QPoint pos = mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, height()));
        view()->parentWidget()->move(pos);
    }
};
```

[image]